# Why does flyway produce a warning message when setting outOfOrder to true?

Tags: java, flyway

I am getting the following warning message in my logs when `outOfOrder` is set to true:

> WARNING: outOfOrder mode is active. Migration run may not be reproducible.

What is the exact meaning of this message? It will be good if someone can tell me what would happen when migration happens. Any example would be helpful.

Comment: What was your reason to set `outOfOrder` to true? [Flyway 2.0: Out Of Order migrations](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/flyway-20-out-order-migrations)

Comment: The reason is that I want flyway to pick any hot fix which I add in the between the main branches. But what I need to know is why does Flyway say that the migration run may not be reproducible?

Comment: Could someone please provide me an answer for the query?

Answer (score 8):

Assume 3 migrations:

1. Create two names 'Tom' and 'Jerry'
2. Add 'Mickey' as a 3rd one
3. Turn names into uppercase

Running with outOfOrder may result in say your migrations applied like this:

1, 3, 2 -> In the DB: TOM, JERRY, Mickey

Re-running it later will produce

1, 2, 3 -> In the DB: TOM, JERRY, MICKEY

This is why outOfOrder is potentially dangerous and the first migration run might not be reproducible.

Comment: So what is the alternative to this?

Answer (score 5):

To add to Axel's answer, not only may the resulting data vary depending on the order, but the migration may not even be possible.  Consider:

Migrations:

1. Create table `foo`
2. Add column `foo.bar`
3. Rename column `foo.bar` to `foo.baz`

Execution order:

- 1, 2, 3 → `foo` has column `baz`
- 1, 3, … → error applying 3: column `foo.bar` not found
- 2, … → error applying 2: table `foo` not found
- 3, … → error applying 3: table `foo` not found

Comment: So what then, would be a best practice to handle hot fixes?  It seems in an environment where folk are actively patching between branches, you're left with no choice but to enable out-of-order migrations, because the newer branch migrations will have a later ID.  I just can't reconcile how one could maintain an older service release branch otherwise, regardless of the migration naming scheme chosen.  Migration dependencies seem to be in order, but that would need to be implemented in house w/ a callback (could admittedly be quite simple).  This is still assumes accurate dependency recording.